# knockoutJS - Element of observableArray is undefined

Tags: knockout.js

I have an observableArray named self.species to which I am pushing data of 2 pokémon species (Example JSON: https://pastebin.com/a6DKFwaM). When I do console.log(self.species()) I get this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeHin.png). However, when I do console.log(self.species()[0]) I get undefined, instead of getting the data of the first pokémon species. Why is that? This is my code (In the HTML I have inputs with data-bind="value: self.species1" and data-bind="value: self.species2" and the button with data-bind="click: getSpecies")

```
    var self = this;
    var baseURL = 'http://0/pokemons/api/EggGroups/';
    self.displayName = 'Pokémon Breed Tester';
    self.error = ko.observable('');
    self.species = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.species1 = ko.observable();
    self.species2 = ko.observable();
    getSpecies = function () {
        self.species.removeAll();
        var URL1 = "http://0/pokemons/api/PokemonSpecies/" + self.species1();
        var URL2 = "http://0/pokemons/api/PokemonSpecies/" + self.species2();
        ajaxHelper(URL1, 'GET').done(function (data) {
            self.species.push(data);
        });
        ajaxHelper(URL2, 'GET').done(function (data) {
            self.species.push(data);
        });
        console.log(self.species());
        console.log(self.species()[0]); //Undefined
    }
    function ajaxHelper(uri, method, data) {
        self.error('');
        return $.ajax({
            type: method,
            url: uri,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: data ? JSON.stringify(data) : null,
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("AJAX Call[" + uri + "] Fail...");
                self.error(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you're fetching your data asynchronously, and JS code is executed synchronously. So when you execute `console.log(self.species())`, `self.species` still contains an empty array. The data arrives at some later point, if maybe only a few miliseconds later. The developer tools are smart enough to recognize that `self.species()` is an expression and it will re-evaluate it when it changes. In your screenshot it shows the little 'i' icon, which will tell you the expression was evaluated just now. However when you do `console.log(self.species()[0])`, what you see in the console is the value of `self.species()[0]` *at that point in time*, which is indeed undefined. It won't get updated in the console when `self.species` changes.

If you change your code to log self.species after the callback is done, you'll notice the difference:

```
ajaxHelper(URL1, 'GET').done(function (data) {
    self.species.push(data);
    console.log(self.species());
    console.log(self.species()[0]);
});
ajaxHelper(URL2, 'GET').done(function (data) {
    self.species.push(data);
    console.log(self.species());
    console.log(self.species()[0]);
});
```

### Addition

If you would like to wait for all requests to be completed, you can utilize [jQuery.when](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) (or use the native [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)):

```
$.when(ajaxHelper(URL1, 'GET'), ajaxHelper(URL2, 'GET')).done(function (data1, data2) {
    // Now both AJAX requests have been completed
    // And the return data is in the (terribly named) parameters
    self.species.push(data1, data2);
    // Now you can safely compare self.species()[0] to self.species()[1]
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense, my Web Tech Introduction teacher didn't explain this. So if I wanted to compare the data in self.species()[0] and self.species()[1] how would I go about it? In the second AjaxHelper function? Or would that not guarantee that the other data has been pushed?

Comment: Exactly; you have no way of knowing for sure which AJAX request will complete first. There are two ways to accomplish that: execute the second function in the done callback for the first one, but this quickly gets messy. A better way is to use jQuery `$.when` to wait for both requests to be completed, and then act accordingly. I'll put a small example in my answer.